# how to return java object as json in heroku java example app

Tags: java, json, heroku, thymeleaf

The Heroku "java-getting started" app, uses thymeleaf,

such that in the main class

```
@RequestMapping("/")
String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

returns the template index.html

however, I wish to have an endpoint returning JSON and not have it templated

eg

```
@RequestMapping("/obj")
Myobject obj() {
    return new Myobject("abc", "fish");
}
```

to return

```
{
    "foo": "abc",
    "bar": "fish"
}
```

but obviously, I currently get an error as it's trying to look up a template by an object

Answer (score 0):

I think all you're looking for is the `@ResponseBody` annotation.  if you annotate a methon on a `@Controller`  with it, it returns the returned object as JSON rather than attempting to resolve a view.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/obj")
Myobject obj() {
    return new Myobject("abc", "fish");
}
```

Alternative, you can can use @RestController instead of @Controller if you wish all methods on a controller to return JSON.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/obj")
    Myobject obj() {
        return new Myobject("abc", "fish");
    }
}
```